# js header:excel

Tags: javascript, excel

Всем привет, есть код, когда он скачивает файл excel, при попытки печати, часть страницы обрезается почти пополам и уезжает на второй лист. Может кто что скажет?

```js
var dopPar = {
            "header":   'excel',  
            "headName": "Название"
        };

var par = "";
var href = "";

for(var j in dopPar) {
            par += j+":"+dopPar[j]+";";
};

href = "./index.php?module="+module+"&par={"+par+";head:true}&reload=false";

 location.href = href;
```

Comment: Каким образом приведённый Вами код относится к проблеме?

Comment: использую его для формирования excel. Может кто приведет другой код, чтобы все хорошо формировалось в excel, но без библиотек

Comment: Вы формируете не Excel, а текст в CSV формате. Не могу только понять, почему Вы не отправляете имеющийся JS объект через POST, а используете GET, ведь при большом CSV длинны URL может и не хватить. Для того, чтоб понять почему Ваша страница при печати выглядит не так, как ожидается - необходим код этой самой страницы (ответ/вывод index.php).